# Strong components in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have written a function to calculate all strong components in a graph.

How do I make this cleaner and nicer?

````
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.min

private fun readLn() = readLine()!! // string line
private fun readInt() = readLn().toInt() // single int
private fun readStrings() = readLn().split(" ") // list of strings
private fun readInts() = readStrings().map { it.toInt() } // list of ints




typealias Graph<T> = Map<T, List<T>>

fun getScc(graph: Graph<String>, allNodes: Set<String>): MutableList<List<String>> {
    val discoveryTime = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    val lowest = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    val stack = ArrayDeque<String>()
    var index = 0
    val strongComponents = mutableListOf<List<String>>()
    val resolved = mutableSetOf<String>()
    fun dfs(node: String) {
        index += 1
        discoveryTime[node] = index
        lowest[node] = index
        stack.addLast(node)
        for (neb in graph[node] ?: mutableListOf()) {
            if (neb in resolved) {
                continue
            }
            if (neb in discoveryTime) { //ancestor
                lowest[node] = min(discoveryTime[neb]!!, lowest[node]!!)
            } else {
                dfs(neb)
                lowest[node] = min(lowest[neb]!!, lowest[node]!!)
            }
        }
        if (lowest[node] == discoveryTime[node]) {
            val sc = mutableListOf<String>()

            val neb = stack.pollLast()!!
            resolved.add(neb)
            sc.add(neb)

            if (neb == node) {
                strongComponents.add(sc)
                return

            }
            while (stack.size > 0 && stack.peekLast()!! != node) {
                val neb = stack.pollLast()!!
                resolved.add(neb)
                sc.add(neb)
            }
            if (stack.size > 0 && stack.peekLast()!! == node) {
                val neb = stack.pollLast()
                resolved.add(neb)
                sc.add(neb)
            }

            strongComponents.add(sc)
        }
    }

    for (node in allNodes) {
        if (node !in resolved) {
            dfs(node)
        }
    }
    return strongComponents
}

```
````

Comment: It would be good, if you could extract the `dfs` function to outside of `getScc` function and give some context (either as text, comment and/or tests) to what the code should fulfill. I will be able to give a more detailed review then.